# CSS not applying to body tag

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have the most basic PHP code with just these 13 lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="design/faq.css" media="display" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    print_r( $_GET );
    echo "hey";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am opening this page as: `faq.php?code=sth`; The PHP code is getting executed correctly, but the CSS is not working at all(in any browser). Since I primarily use Opera, here are screenshots:

1. Parsed Page
   [image: Parsed page]
2. Code
   [image: Code]
3. The `faq.css`
   [image: CSS]

## What I tried

- My first instinct was to check if the `faq.css` was accessible or not. Yes, the file has write property as **0644** same as all other files.
- Then I checked if the path was not getting parsed correctly, but that is not the case either, as I later tried it with full path too.

## Trouble

I am completely stumped at such a behavior from the least troublesome of languages as CSS. What could be the problem here? The CSS file contains only these 4 lines.

```
body {
    background-color: #DC2826;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: If it is CSS problem then it should be only incorrect file path.

Comment: @Mr_Green You can see that he is browsing the CSS file in the element inspector. That means it is correctly linked to the document.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: have you tried adding size to your `Body` tag?  or adding the style to another tag such as `<p>` or `<h1>` and giving it a size i.e. height and width?

Comment: @j08691 I am living in a college with same IP being shared by 1000s of us. The page is not hosted on local intranet only.

Comment: @Eric ya I have not seen that

Comment: @all [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12679264/1190388) answer by Eric solved it. Will accept the answer as soon as 10 minutes pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `media="display"`. This is not a valid type for the `media` attribute.

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp) for valid types of devices (`all`, `aural`, `braille`, `handheld`, `projection`, `print`, `screen`, `tty`, `tv`).